# load breakpoint file error

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I have previously saved list of breakpoints using

```
save breakpoints blist
```

now after compiling the program when I try to reload the same break points with the load command

```
load blist
```

I get this error

```
You can't do that when your target is `exec'
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 17):

> load blist

Try `source blist` instead.

From `"help save breakpoints"`:

```
Save current breakpoint definitions as a script.
```

The way to read a script is the `source` command. The `load` command means something different entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I have breakpoints saved to file, say **gdb.br**, file content looks like:

```
br /project/src/file.c : 100
commands
silent
printf "\nbacktrace:\n"
bt
cont
end
```

This break just output backtrace and continue execution. You may also use simple breaks, like:

```
br /project/src/file.c : 100
br className::methodName
```

I have a lot of breaks there - gdb fails to add them via copy-past. Also I can't use *load* command on my multi-threading system.
To attach with gdb and load breakpoints I use this sequence:

```
gdb -p 1523 -x gdb.br
```

Where **1523** is process pid you want to attach to. **-x** is  primarily 
 intedent to be used to load commands, set environment, but also could be used to load your breaks.
Hope this will help.